# Finding a List Position Represented by a Variable

Tags: python-3.x, list, pycharm

Basically I have a variable equal to a number and want to find the number in the position represented by the variable.  This is what I

```
numbertocheck =1
loopcriteria = 1
while loopcriteria == 1:
    if numbertocheck in ticketnumber:
        entryhour.append[numbertocheck] = currenttime.hour
        entryminute.append[numbertocheck] = currenttime.minute
        print("Thank you.  Your ticket number is", numbertocheck)
        print("There are now", available_spaces, "spaces available.")
        loopcriteria = 2
```

I get this error (in pyCharm):

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/Users/user1/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2017.3/scratches/scratch_2.py",
>   line 32, in  entryhour.append[numbertocheck] =
>   currenttime.hour TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object does
>   not support item assignment

How do I do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Show what is the content of ticketnumber

Answer (score 0):

Though you haven't provided the complete code, I think you only have problem with using append. You cannot use `[]` just after an `append`. To insert into a particular position, you need `insert`

Putting the relevant lines you need to replace below...

```
        entryhour.insert(numbertocheck,currenttime.hour)
        entryminute.insert(numbertocheck,currenttime.minute)
        # available_spaces-=1 # guessing you need this too here?
```

P.S. your loop doesn't seem to make sense, I hope you debug it yourself if it doesn't work the way you want.